# How to modify executed Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to find a raw which satisfies, most conditions.

I have a model called `SLA`; I am trying to find one `SLA`.

I have 2 `SLAs`

- `SLA1 :
  type = 1`
- `SLA2
  type = 1
  department = 2`

When I call:

```
sla($type=1,$user_id=“”,$dept=“”,$source=“”,$priority=“”);
```

it returns `SLA1`. When I call:

```
sla($type=1,$user_id=“”,$dept=1,$source=“”,$priority=“”);
```

it returns `SLA1` instead of `SLA2`. Here's my code:

```
function sla($type = "", $userid = "", $department = "", $source = "", $priority = "") {
    $sla = \App\Model\helpdesk\Manage\Sla\Sla_plan::
            where(function($query)use($type, $department, $source) {
                $query->where(function($q) use($department) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($department,apply_sla_depertment)");

                        })
                        ->where(function($q) use($type) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($type,apply_sla_tickettype)");

                        })
                        ->where(function($q) use($source) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($source,apply_sla_ticketsource)");

                        });
            })
            ->orWhere(function($query)use($type, $department, $source) {
                $query->orWhere(function($q) use($department) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($department,apply_sla_depertment)");

                        })
                        ->orWhere(function($q) use($type) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($type,apply_sla_tickettype)");

                        })
                        ->orWhere(function($q) use($source) {
                            $q->whereRaw("find_in_set($source,apply_sla_ticketsource)");

                        });
            });
    dd($sla->first());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can't do just with builder, You have to use collection methods too

this is my answer, please check this

```
$sla = \App\Model\helpdesk\Manage\Sla\Sla_plan::
            where('status',1)
            ->where(function($query)use($type, $department, $source, $company) {
                $query
                ->where(function($query)use($type, $department, $source, $company) {
                    $query 
                    ->when($type, function($query)use($type) {
                       $query->orWhereRaw("find_in_set($type,apply_sla_tickettype)");
                    })
                    ->when($department, function($query)use($department) {
                       $query->orWhereRaw("find_in_set($department,apply_sla_depertment)");
                    })
                    ->when($source, function($query)use($source) {
                       $query->orWhereRaw("find_in_set($source,apply_sla_ticketsource)");
                    })
               });

            });
$all = $sla->get();
    if ($all->count() > 0) {
        $collection = $all->mapWithKeys(function($value)use($type, $department, $source,$company) {
            $array = [$value->id => 0];
            if (is_array($value->apply_sla_tickettype) && in_array($type, $value->apply_sla_tickettype)) {
                $array[$value->id] ++;
            }
            if (is_array($value->apply_sla_depertment) && in_array($department, $value->apply_sla_depertment)) {
                $array[$value->id] ++;
            }
            if (is_array($value->apply_sla_ticketsource) && in_array($source, $value->apply_sla_ticketsource)) {
                $array[$value->id] ++;
            }
            return $array;
        });
        $array = $collection->toArray();
        if ($array) {
            $maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));
            return $maxs[0];
        }
    }
```